# Simplification of mathematic expressions using Inheritance tree model

Tags: java, inheritance, arithmetic-expressions, simplify

I have been struggling to find a solution for this problem. Or maybe an approach that will suit my conditions of problem.

We represent math expressions by classes arranged in a hierarchy tree. At top there is base math expression and below binary, unary, and below them all the operators such that unary represent: negation, cos, sin. Binary: plus, minus, division, pow, log.

Aside we have number and variable.

An example of expression:

```
new Plus(new Plus(x , 5), 5) => x + 5 + 5
```

All of this classes implement an interface with methods that are usually related to `.math`.

Fore xample: evaluate, assign, derive. This methods work recursively thanks to the hierarchy tree.

I noticed also that this is not a common regulary binary tree. (Am I right?)

Everything goes nice and smooth until the part we have to do a simplification to those expressions.

Basic simplification of x * 0 => 0 is simple.

But I want to simplify using associativity, distributivity also..

For example given( 2*x + 4*x ) + 5 + 2x will give me 8x + 5.

So I am wondering how to approach this problem.

Comment: Your question is basically too broad to be answered here. Basically you would have to sit down with a tutor and talk about this for quite some time. If we are really supposed to help you, you should give us a real [mcve]. Right now, you are explaining a lot of things about your code. Instead, you should show us *just enough* code so that we can see your problem in code, instead of **assuming** what your explanations actually mean.

Comment: You approach it step by step. First you must define what a simplification should be. In your example the first simplification would be "remove unnecessary brackets". Or you could start with a simplification that adds the constants 2*x+4*x if the variable is on both sides the same. Small steps.